# How do I connect Angular2 router to ngrx/store?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ngrx

I'm using ngrx/store to manage state in my Angular2 application.

How can I connect the latest (3.0.0) router in Angular2 to ngrx/store. The method provided here is regarding the old Angular2 router: https://github.com/CodeSequence/ngrx-store-router

Basicaly what I want to do is to have my router as part of my state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subsequent release of [CodeSequence/ngrx-store-router](https://github.com/CodeSequence/ngrx-store-router) - version [0.4.0](https://github.com/CodeSequence/ngrx-store-router/commit/44c8d59bd710b5a04a1c4c434a0e0e1669915262) - added support for the v3 Angular Router.